# how to get object in angularjs to replace $.fn of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There is a jquery statement,
var zTree = $.fn.zTree.getZTreeObj("treediv");
now, i want to call it in angularjs, how to implement it in angularjs? thanks for your help.

```
<div id="treediv">
 <ul tree id="tree" class="ztree" ng-model="selectNode" />
</div>

 var zTree = $.fn.zTree.getZTreeObj("treediv");
 var changedNodes = zTree.getChangeCheckedNodes()
```

Comment: If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function.

Comment: "There is my Vanilla js statement: `renderTree();` How to implement it with jQuery?" - Your question looks same. In common, it's impossible to say how to do it. If you need just call without any data binding - then call it as is.

Comment: You can create some provider for your global accessible zTree library for start, like angular does it for [$window](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/window.js)

Comment: i try to  var treediv=angular.element("#zTree").getZTreeObj("treediv"); it throws angular.element(...).getZTreeObj is not a function

Comment: what is your index.html looks like? you have to make sure jquery script is loaded before angularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` inside angular (directives are best place). But seems that function is added by a 3rd party lib so make sure you have that registered in a global place after `jQuery`:

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$scope', function(scope) {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.doSomething = function() {
         var zTree = $.fn.zTree.getZTreeObj("treediv");
         var changedNodes = zTree.getChangeCheckedNodes();
      }
  }

  return {
    link: link
  };
}]);
```

And in your html:

```
<div id="treediv">
    <ul tree id="tree" class="ztree" my-directive ng-click="doSomething()" ng-model="selectNode" />
</div>
```

Comment: @btinoco some people are nervous these days :)